# linq to SQL with aggregate functions

Tags: linq, entity-framework, aggregate, entities

I have spent a great deal of time trying to convert the query below to linq to entities.

```
SELECT ItemCode, AVG([Count]) As [Count]
FROM [tblHistory]
GROUP BY ItemCode
ORDER BY [Count] desc
```

In my entity framework edmx, I have a `tblHistory` with fields

```
{ ItemCode(int), Count(int), Date(datetime) }
```

I am able to group by one column and display that particular column (in this case `Count`) but to access `ItemCode` in the same context is giving me trouble.

One of the methods that I tried to use is below:

```
 var query = from p in Context.tblHistories
             group p by p.ItemCode into g
             select new tblHistory
                        {
                            ItemCode = g.Key,
                            Count = from c in g select new { c.Count }
                        };
```

Please let me know if additional info is required for anyone who has knowledge of this as I will gladly provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tblHistories.GroupBy(p => p.ItemCode)
         .Select(g => new { ItemCode = g.Key, Count = g.Average (c => c.Count)})
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x => new tblHistory{ ItemCode = x.ItemCode, Count = (int)x.Count })
```

Comment: Should be `OrderByDescending` instead.

Comment: thanks alot for your response, I tried using the query syntax that you provided, there is one problem. I am creating the query in a function that is returning IEnumerable<tblHistory>. to do this I have     select new <tblHistory>{ ItemCode = g.Key, Count = g.Average(c => c.Count) }).OrderBy(x => x.Count) and I get error of cast between double and int, do you have any guidance as to why this is happening? thanks again

Comment: @Sue I have updated the answer to address the problems you mention.